# (xcode) Counter app. Need to save a value of an integer.

Tags: ios, load, integer, save

i'm creating a counter app and I want to save the value of TotalCount each time I touch the button up and I want to load it automatically when the app is open. Can you tell me what can I add to save my value of TotalCount.

The GoStats action is a button that I touch to see my stats, a page where there is the TotalCount. When I touch the button, the NumberCount (number of counter) is coming back to 0 so as to I can count from the beginning.

People tell me that I have to use NSUserDefaults but I don't know how, maybe if you other idea just tell me. I really need it for my apps so your help will be really important for me.

Here is my ViewController.h :

```
int NumberCount;
int TotalCount;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *points;
- (IBAction)GoStats:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Counter;
- (IBAction)Up:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Reset:(id)sender;



@end
```

And here is my ViewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)Up:(id)sender
{

NumberCount = NumberCount +1;
TotalCount = TotalCount +1;
_Counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", NumberCount];


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
points.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", TotalCount];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)GoStats:(id)sender {
    NumberCount = 0;

}



- (IBAction)Reset:(id)sender {
TotalCount = 0;
_points.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", TotalCount];

}

@end
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you read the docs for `NSUserDefaults` or have you done any searching on how to use it? Do a little research and try something. If you get stuck, post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Save integer into UserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:intToBeSaved forKey:@"SavedInt"];

//Load integer from UserDefaults
loadedInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SavedInt"]
```

It's pretty straight forward, as others have said you should try googling before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you should use `NSUserDefaults`.  Here's [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html)

Here's an example of storing and retrieving an integer:

```
static NSString * const kUserDefaultsCount = @"Count";
- (void)storeCountInDefaults:(NSInteger)number
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:number forKey:kUserDefaultsCount];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
- (NSInteger)getCountFromDefaults
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kUserDefaultsCount];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add task to NSUserDefault array and store it. Do this when your total count is updated
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:totalCount forKey:@"keyInt"]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]];

//Before displaying your the total count value, get the new value from NSUserDefaults
TotalCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:WEATHER_KEY]];
```

I'd recommend reading the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html